# Solve $x^2-y^2=2xyz$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Find all the integer solutions of
>   $$x^2-y^2=2xyz.$$

I tried to factorise it, but I failed. Somebody help me.

Comment: One thing is that we may assume $x,y$ to be odd numbers because if only one of them are even, equation would not be satisfied and both are even, then we can divide each side by 4.

Comment: Also, we may safely assume that $x,y$ are relatively prime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With $q=\dfrac xy$,

$$q^2-2zq-1=0.$$

The discriminant $z^2+1$ is never a perfect square so that $q$ is irrational except for the case $\color{green}{z=0}$ implying $\color{green}{x^2=y^2}$, to which we need to add the case of $y=0$, that is $\color{green}{x=y=0}$ ($z$ free).

Answer (score 1):

Well you can always look at the equation as a polynomial of $x$:

$$x^2 - 2yzx - y^2=0$$

Now

$$\Delta=4y^2z^2+4y^2=4y^2(z^2+1)$$

And finally

$$x_1=\frac{2yz-\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}=\frac{2yz-2y\sqrt{z^2+1}}{2}=yz-y\sqrt{z^2+1}$$

Analogously

$$x_2=yz+y\sqrt{z^2+1}$$

Now obviously we can pick $y$ arbitrarly and all we need is to either ensure that $\sqrt{z^2+1}$ is an integer **or** pick $y=0$. For the first case this can only be true for $z=0$ (I leave it as an exercise). For the second case we obtain solutions $x=y=0$ with $z$ arbitrary.

Thus only possible integer solutions are: ($x=\pm y$, $z=0$) and ($x=y=0$, $z$ arbitrary).

Answer (score 1):

If $x=0$ or $y=0$ then the only solutions are $(0,0,b)$.

Otherwise, we may assume that $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime.

But then $x \mid y^2$ and $y \mid x^2$ imply $x=\pm 1$ and $y=\pm 1$ and so $z=0$.

Therefore, the only solutions are $(a,\pm a,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, $$x^2-y^2=2xyz $$ $$\Rightarrow x^2-2xyz-y^2=0$$ $$x = \frac {2yz \pm \sqrt {4y^2zz^2+4y^2}}{2} $$ $$\Rightarrow x = y (z \pm \sqrt {z^2+1}) $$

We can easily see that a trivial integer solution is $$(0,0,z) \,\, \forall z \in \mathbb Z $$ Since, **for $x,y,z \in \mathbb Z $**, the only integer $z$ for which $z^2+1$ will be a perfect square is zero, the other integer solutions are $$(a, \pm a,0) $$

Consider the case when $x,y,z \neq 0$. Then we have, $$x^2-y^2 =2xyz \Leftrightarrow \frac {x}{y}- \frac {y}{x} = 2z $$ Now when $x $ and $y $ are not equal as well as non-zero *atleast one of the terms in the LHS is not an integer* (why?) but the RHS is an integer (*remember the condition?*). So, this case yields no solution.

Hope it helps.